# Fazer INSERT e UPDATE em duas tabelas com foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

Boas!

Talvez eu esteja fazendo tudo da maneira errada, mas vou tentar explicar ao máximo o que ocorreu com meu problema. Vamos lá:

Tenho um banco de dados chamado **escola**, nesse banco de dados tenho 3 tabelas:

**turmas**: id_turma (primary key), nome_turma

**alunos**: id_aluno (primary key), id_turma (foreign key de turmas(id_turma)), nome_aluno, email_aluno, nascimento_aluno, situacao_aluno

**notas**: id_nota, id_aluno(foreign key de alunos(id_aluno)), id_turma(foreign key de turmas(id_turma)), media1, media2, media3, media4, mediafinal.

A questão é: na hora de criar um novo aluno pelo formulário, existirão as opções de:

- Nome Aluno
- Email Aluno
- Nascimento Aluno
- Turma Aluno (será puxado o foreign de turma e armazenado em id_turma na tabela alunos)
- Media 1 (aqui entra o problema, media fica na tabela notas e todo o restante fica na tabela alunos e a relação se dá pelo id_aluno na tabela notas)
- Media 2 (aqui entra o problema, media fica na tabela notas e todo o restante fica na tabela alunos e a relação se dá pelo id_aluno na tabela notas)
- Media 3 (aqui entra o problema, media fica na tabela notas e todo o restante fica na tabela alunos e a relação se dá pelo id_aluno na tabela notas)
- Media 4 (aqui entra o problema, media fica na tabela notas e todo o restante fica na tabela alunos e a relação se dá pelo id_aluno na tabela notas)

**QUESTÃO:** Como faço para fazer INSERT ou UPDATE na tabela alunos e notas, relacionando eles?

**SQL**

```
--
-- Índices para tabela `alunos`
--
ALTER TABLE `alunos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_aluno`),
  ADD KEY `fk_turma` (`id_turma`);

--
-- Índices para tabela `notas`
--
ALTER TABLE `notas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`nota_id`),
  ADD KEY `id_aluno` (`id_aluno`),
  ADD KEY `id_turma` (`id_turma`);

--
-- Índices para tabela `turma`
--
ALTER TABLE `turma`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_turma`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de tabelas despejadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de tabela `alunos`
--
ALTER TABLE `alunos`
  MODIFY `id_aluno` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de tabela `turma`
--
ALTER TABLE `turma`
  MODIFY `id_turma` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

--
-- Restrições para despejos de tabelas
--

--
-- Limitadores para a tabela `alunos`
--
ALTER TABLE `alunos`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_turma` FOREIGN KEY (`id_turma`) REFERENCES `turma` (`id_turma`);

--
-- Limitadores para a tabela `notas`
--
ALTER TABLE `notas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `notas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_aluno`) REFERENCES `alunos` (`id_aluno`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `notas_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_turma`) REFERENCES `turma` (`id_turma`);
COMMIT;
```

**classe Aluno.php**

```
class Aluno {

    private string $nome;
    private string $email;
    private $nascimento;
    private int $turma;
    private string $nome_turma;
    private $media1;
    private $media2;
    private $media3;
    private $media4;

    public function setNomeAluno($n_a) {

        $this->nome = $n_a;

    }
    public function getNomeAluno() {

        return $this->nome;

    }

    public function setEmailAluno($e_a) {

        $this->email = $e_a;

    }
    public function getEmailAluno() {

        return $this->email;

    }

    public function setNascimentoAluno($nsc_a) {

        $this->nascimento = new DateTime($nsc_a);

    }
    public function getNascimentoAluno() {

        return $this->nascimento->format('d/m/Y');

    }

    public function setTurmaAluno($t_a) {

        $this->turma = $t_a;

    }
    public function getTurmaAluno() {

        return $this->turma;

    }

    public function setNomeTurma($nt_a) {

        $this->nome_turma = $nt_a;

    }
    public function getNomeTurma() {

        return $this->nome_turma;

    }

    public function setMedia1($m) {

        $this->media1 = $m;

    }
    public function getMedia1() {

        return $this->media1;

    }

    public function setMedia2($m1) {

        $this->media2 = $m1;

    }
    public function getMedia2() {

        return $this->media2;

    }

    public function setMedia3($m3) {

        $this->media3 = $m3;

    }
    public function getMedia3() {

        return $this->media3;

    }

    public function setMedia4($m4) {

        $this->media4 = $m4;

    }
    public function getMedia4() {

        return $this->media4;

    }

}
```

**cadastro.php**

```
prepare("SELECT * FROM turma");
$consulta->execute();
$data = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

?>


    

        

            Cadastrar Novo Aluno

        

        

            

                

                    

                        Nome Completo do Aluno
                        

                    

                    

                        E-mail Institucional
                        

                    

                

                

                    

                        Data de Nascimento
                        

                    

                    

                        Turma
                        


                        
                            Selecione

                       
                            id_turma ?>">nome_turma ?>

                        

                        
                        
                    

                

                

                    

                        Média 1
                        

                    

                    

                        Média 2
                        

                    

                    

                        Média 3
                        

                    

                    

                        Média 4
```

**valida_dados.php**

```
require("config.php");
require("autoload.php");


if(isset($_POST['nome']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['nascimento']) && isset($_POST['turma'])) {


    // Seting up variables
    $aluno = new Aluno();
    $aluno->setNomeAluno($_POST['nome']);
    $aluno->setEmailAluno($_POST['email']);
    $aluno->setNascimentoAluno($_POST['nascimento']);
    $aluno->setTurmaAluno($_POST['turma']);
    $aluno->setMedia1($_POST['media1']);
    $aluno->setMedia2($_POST['media2']);
    $aluno->setMedia3($_POST['media3']);
    $aluno->setMedia4($_POST['media4']);

    // Geting variables
    $nome = $aluno->getNomeAluno();
    $email = $aluno->getEmailAluno();
    $nascimento = $aluno->getNascimentoAluno();
    $turma = $aluno->getTurmaAluno();
    $media1 = $aluno->getMedia1();
    $media2 = $aluno->getMedia2();
    $media3 = $aluno->getMedia3();
    $media4 = $aluno->getMedia4();

    // Putting data records in database
    $insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO alunos (nome_aluno, id_turma) VALUES (:nome_aluno, :id_turma)");
    $insert->bindValue(':nome_aluno', $nome);
    $insert->bindValue(':id_turma', $turma);
    $insert->execute();
    $rows = $insert->rowCount();

    if ($rows > 0) {

        header("location: index.php");

    }

}
```

Comment: Seja benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Experimente fazer um exemplo mínimo reproduzível. 

Para melhorar sua experiência aqui, fazer a pergunta de forma que possa ser respondida, recomendo ler: [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Obrigado!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tem uma função do MySQL que se chama `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, ela retorna o id do último registro adicionado através do `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
Vou fazer algumas adições no seu `valida_dados.php`:

```php
require("config.php");
require("autoload.php");


if(isset($_POST['nome']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['nascimento']) && isset($_POST['turma'])) {


    // Seting up variables
    $aluno = new Aluno();
    $aluno->setNomeAluno($_POST['nome']);
    $aluno->setEmailAluno($_POST['email']);
    $aluno->setNascimentoAluno($_POST['nascimento']);
    $aluno->setTurmaAluno($_POST['turma']);
    $aluno->setMedia1($_POST['media1']);
    $aluno->setMedia2($_POST['media2']);
    $aluno->setMedia3($_POST['media3']);
    $aluno->setMedia4($_POST['media4']);

    // Geting variables
    $nome = $aluno->getNomeAluno();
    $email = $aluno->getEmailAluno();
    $nascimento = $aluno->getNascimentoAluno();
    $turma = $aluno->getTurmaAluno();
    $media1 = $aluno->getMedia1();
    $media2 = $aluno->getMedia2();
    $media3 = $aluno->getMedia3();
    $media4 = $aluno->getMedia4();

    // Putting data records in database
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO alunos (nome_aluno, id_turma) VALUES (:nome_aluno, :id_turma)");
        $insert->bindValue(':nome_aluno', $nome);
        $insert->bindValue(':id_turma', $turma);
        $insert->execute();
        
        $select = $pdo->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS `id`;");
        $id = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['id']; // Retorna o id do último aluno adicionado
        $notasStatement = $pdo->prepare("ISNERT INTO notas (id_aluno, id_turma, media1, media2, media3, media4, media_final) VALUES (...);");
        // Aqui faça o bind dos values
        // ...
        $notasStatement->execute();
        $rows = $notasStatement->rowCount();
    
        if ($rows > 0) {
            $pdo->commit();
            header("location: index.php");
        }
    } catch (Exception $error) {
        $pdo->rollBack();
    }

}
```

Nesse novo código, eu adicionei a função `LAST_INSERT_ID()` para retornar o id do aluno adicionado e criar o registro na tabela `notas`, também adicionei outros métodos do `PDO`: o `beginTransaction()`, `rollBack()` e `commit()`.
O `beginTransaction()` indica que as modificações feitas na BD não serão permanentes a não ser que você execute o `commit()`. Quando você tiver mais de uma declaração SQL que faça alterações nos dados, é bom fazer isso para manter a integridade da sua BD. O `rollBack()` descarta as alterações feitas após o `beginTransaction()`.